# RGBD-SLAM error

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to run the rgbdslam algorithm by following the instructions described in http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam. This is what I get when I type in the command rosmake rgbdslam_freiburg

[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['rgbdslam_freiburg']
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/samme/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121216-143500
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['rgbdslam_freiburg'] to:
['rgbdslam']
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> opencv2 [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslang  No Makefile in package roslang
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< opencv2 ROS_NOBUILD in package opencv2
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> bullet [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< geometry_msgs  No Makefile in package geometry_msgs
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< bullet ROS_NOBUILD in package bullet
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp  No Makefile in package roscpp
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< sensor_msgs  No Makefile in package sensor_msgs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> angles [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< angles ROS_NOBUILD in package angles
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roswtf [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rospy  No Makefile in package rospy
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> image_geometry [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosconsole  No Makefile in package rosconsole
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roswtf  No Makefile in package roswtf
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< image_geometry ROS_NOBUILD in package image_geometry
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbag [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rostest  No Makefile in package rostest
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< message_filters  No Makefile in package message_filters
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> tf [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< std_msgs  No Makefile in package std_msgs
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosbuild  No Makefile in package rosbuild
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> pcl [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbag  No Makefile in package rosbag
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< tf ROS_NOBUILD in package tf
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> smclib [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosservice [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< smclib ROS_NOBUILD in package smclib
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> common_rosdeps [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslib  No Makefile in package roslib
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< pcl ROS_NOBUILD in package pcl
No Makefile in package pcl
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> cv_bridge [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosservice  No Makefile in package rosservice
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< cv_bridge ROS_NOBUILD in package cv_bridge
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> dynamic_reconfigure [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> pluginlib [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> bond [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< common_rosdeps ROS_NOBUILD in package common_rosdeps
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> visualization_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< pluginlib ROS_NOBUILD in package pluginlib
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< bond ROS_NOBUILD in package bond
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< dynamic_reconfigure ROS_NOBUILD in package dynamic_reconfigure
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> mk [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< mk  No Makefile in package mk
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> bondcpp [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> orocos_kdl [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> opencv_tests [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< opencv_tests ROS_NOBUILD in package opencv_tests
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< bondcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package bondcpp
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< orocos_kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package orocos_kdl
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> python_orocos_kdl [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< visualization_msgs  No Makefile in package visualization_msgs
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> nodelet [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< nodelet ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< python_orocos_kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package python_orocos_kdl
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> kdl [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> nodelet_topic_tools [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package kdl
No Makefile in package kdl
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< nodelet_topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet_topic_tools
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> pcl_ros [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> tf_conversions [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> eigen_conversions [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< pcl_ros ROS_NOBUILD in package pcl_ros
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rgbdslam [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< tf_conversions ROS_NOBUILD in package tf_conversions
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< eigen_conversions ROS_NOBUILD in package eigen_conversions
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> cv_markers [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< cv_markers ROS_NOBUILD in package cv_markers
[ rosmake ] Last 40 linesbdslam: 1.1 sec ]            [ 1 Active 39/40 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `targets'. make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/samme/fuerte_workspace/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/test'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/samme/fuerte_workspace/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/test' cd sample ; make linux-g++ make[2]: Entering directory` /home/samme/fuerte_workspace/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/sample'
make targets 
"ANNLIB = libANN.a" 
"C++ = g++" 
"CFLAGS = -O3" 
"MAKELIB = ar ruv" 
"RANLIB = true"
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/samme/fuerte_workspace/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/sample' make[3]: Nothing to be done for` targets'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/samme/fuerte_workspace/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/sample' make[2]: Leaving directory` /home/samme/fuerte_workspace/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/sample'
cd ann2fig ; make linux-g++
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/samme/fuerte_workspace/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/ann2fig' make targets \ "ANNLIB = libANN.a" \ "C++ = g++" \ "CFLAGS = -O3" \ "MAKELIB = ar ruv" \ "RANLIB = true" make[3]: Entering directory` /home/samme/fuerte_workspace/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/ann2fig'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `targets'. make[3]: Leaving directory` /home/samme/fuerte_workspace/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/ann2fig'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/samme/fuerte_workspace/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2/ann2fig' make[1]: Leaving directory` /home/samme/fuerte_workspace/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/external/gicp/ann_1.1.2'

---

### -- Eigen found (include: /usr/include/eigen3)
[rosbuild] Couldn't find source file /home/samme/fuerte_workspace/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/build/src/moc_qtros.cxx; assuming that it is in /home/samme/fuerte_workspace/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam and will be generated later
[rosbuild] Couldn't find source file /home/samme/fuerte_workspace/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/build/src/moc_openni_listener.cxx; assuming that it is in /home/samme/fuerte_workspace/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam and will be generated later
[rosbuild] Couldn't find source file /home/samme/fuerte_workspace/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/build/src/moc_qt_gui.cxx; assuming that it is in /home/samme/fuerte_workspace/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam and will be generated later
[rosbuild] Couldn't find source file /home/samme/fuerte_workspace/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/build/src/moc_graph_manager.cxx; assuming that it is in /home/samme/fuerte_workspace/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam and will be generated later
[rosbuild] Couldn't find source file /home/samme/fuerte_workspace/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/build/src/moc_glviewer.cxx; assuming that it is in /home/samme/fuerte_workspace/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam and will be generated later
[rosbuild] Couldn't find source file /home/samme/fuerte_workspace/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam/build/src/moc_ros_service_ui.cxx; assuming that it is in /home/samme/fuerte_workspace/rgbdslam_freiburg/rgbdslam and will be generated later
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

[ rosmake ] Output from build of package rgbdslam written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/samme/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121216-143500/rgbdslam/build_output.log
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rgbdslam [FAIL] [ 1.16 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package rgbdslam.
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:
[ rosmake ] Built 40 packages with 1 failures.
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
[ rosmake ] /home/samme/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121216-143500

I am very new to ROS and am not sure where the error is coming from. Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Khalid Yousif

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50575/rgbd-slam-error/) by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 735 on 2012-12-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I recall correctly, this is an issue with g2o. Try `roscd g2o`, and if you get an error, that is your first problem. If you do change to the g2o directory, try `rosmake g2o`. If it doesn't make correctly, you might need to install dependencies with `rosdep install g2o`. Beyond that, I can't give more specifics without further knowledge of the error.

---

Originally posted by [autorover](https://answers.ros.org/users/3785/autorover/) with karma: 93 on 2012-12-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K_Yousif](https://answers.ros.org/users/3767/k_yousif/) on 2012-12-16**:
Thanks for your fast response, I tried roscd g2o and I got: roscd: No such package/stack 'g2o'.
note: in the rgbdslam_freiburg folder there is an empty g2o folder.

What do you recommend?

**Comment by [autorover](https://answers.ros.org/users/3785/autorover/) on 2012-12-17**:
With the error you posted, ROS can't find the g2o package. You should move it to a location that can be found or add the location it is in the the ros package path, either manually with $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH or with rosws. roscd should find the g2o folder if you do it correctly.